# HashSet.contains() changes from true to false after persisting parent entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, equals, lombok

I'm having trouble to remove a child entity from a one-to-many relationship. I managed to narrow it down to `HashSet.contains()` returning false only after the parent (and child) entity is persisted.

The following code

```
Parent parent = ParentFactory.parent();
Child child = ChildFactory.child();
parent.addChild(child);
System.out.println("contains? " + parent.getChilds().contains(child));
System.out.println("child.hashCode " + child.hashCode());
System.out.println("parent.child.hashCode " + parent.getChilds().iterator().next().hashCode());
System.out.println("equals? " + parent.getChilds().iterator().next().equals(child));
parentDao.save(parent);
System.out.println("contains? " + parent.getChilds().contains(child));
System.out.println("child.hashCode " + child.hashCode());
System.out.println("parent.child.hashCode " + parent.getChilds().iterator().next().hashCode());
System.out.println("equals? " + parent.getChilds().iterator().next().equals(child));
```

Will print:

```
contains? true
child.hashCode 911563320
parent.child.hashCode 911563320
equals? true
contains? false
child.hashCode -647032511
parent.child.hashCode -647032511
equals? true
```

I read in [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603204/java-crazyness-contains-fails-when-equals-passes), that it could be caused by overloading instead of overriding `equals()`, but I think that that can't be the problem because then it'd print false the first time I check `contains()`. By the way, I'm using Lombok's `EqualsAndHashCode`.

My entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parents")
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public class Parent implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6063061402030020L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private Boolean isActive;

    @OneToMany(fetch = EAGER, mappedBy = "parent", cascade = {ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
    private final Set<Child> childs = new HashSet<>();

    public void addChild(Child child) {
        this.childs.add(child);
        child.setParent(this);
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "childs")
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "parent")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString(exclude = "parent")
public class Child implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5086351007045447L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentId_fk")
    private Parent parent;
}
```

The only thing that changes after persist is the `child`'s id, but that both `child` and `parent.child` reference to the same instance, so the id is the same. This is proven by `hashCode()` and `equals()` returning true.
Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

Comment: If the hashcode changes, then hash based collections cannot find the object anymore. But if the hashcode changes, it also means that you have a totally different object, and you should not use those in hashset.

Comment: What is the value of `id` before and after saving? Since that is auto-assigned, I would imagine that is what is changing, and thus changing the hash code.

Answer (score 3):

You have broken the contract for `equals` and `hashCode`, to keep them same for the life of the object:

```
contains? true
child.hashCode 911563320
parent.child.hashCode 911563320
equals? true
//persist happens here
contains? false
child.hashCode -647032511
parent.child.hashCode -647032511
equals? true
```

You can see that the `hashCode` has changed and that's all it takes to break the `Set`.

---

You can exclude the id field from Lombok's generated `equals` and `hashCode` methods as this:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude={"id"})
```

#### Comments

> it could be caused by overloading instead of overriding equals(), but I think that that can't be the problem because then it'd print false the first time I check contains()

It would not print `false`, because when you call `addChild`, only adding the child to the `Set` takes place. No id is assigned until you persist the changes with `save`. If the id was assigned upon adding to the set, you wouldn't have this problem.

> The only thing that changes after persist is the child's id, but that both child and parent.child reference to the same instance, so the id is the same. This is proven by hashCode() and equals() returning true.

The only thing that changed is indeed the id, but thats the problem - if the set was somehow smarter and could detect changes in stored objects, it could reflect the change in `hashCode` and return proper object what you call `contains` for the second time. But that didnt happen. `equals` return `true` because references didn't change, not even in the set. `contains? false` does not mean the set is empty, it merely means it can't find the object by `-647032511` hash code, because it was stored with `911563320` hash code. If you somehow pass an object with `911563320` hash code, it will happily return the instance with `-647032511` hash (not sure here, maybe it will throw exception, but the point is it will try to return object with different hash).

Also note that you could now add the very same object twice in the set, which is also against the `Set` contract. Iterator of the set would return one object with same identity twice - you don't want it to happen.

Answer (score 2):

`HashSet` uses `hashCode` to find the right bucket in which to put given element. When you search given element with `contains` it again calls `hashCode` on the object, but when it returns new value, it cannot find it on the place where it was inserted and thus returns false. Maybe `save` operation causes an object to have different hashCode.

Answer (score 2):

The `@EqualsAndHashCode` annotation uses the member variables to create a hashcode. When `persist`ing an object, it is assigned an id, which means that the hashcode will differ before and after the persist. If the annotation is the one from Lombok you can exclude fields.